# ol.inherits in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I'm testing OpenLayers 6 beta.
ol.inherits looks missing in OpenLayers 6.

```
ol.inherits(ol.source.NowMap, ol.source.OSM);
```

This causes error

```
Uncaught TypeError: ol.inherits is not a function
```

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mentioned in the update notes https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md

A simple fix which the ol-ext library uses is to replace it with the something based on the old function

```
var ol_ext_inherits = function(child,parent) {
  child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
  child.prototype.constructor = child;
};
```

or see the OL6 examples for a method which will need some recoding
https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/custom-controls.html
https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/custom-interactions.html

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just a notice, as I do not have the reputation points requred for a proper comment. The suggested solutions is actually more in line with recomendations than the code given in the actual OpenLayers examples that are linked. Namely, the `__proto__` method is deprecated and the proper method for inheritance is by using `Object.create()`. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Cheers,

Miha

Comment: You may want consider to edit the answer you are referring to rather than adding a new answer or add a link to your answer which clearly states which answer you are referring to - there may be more answers added in time.

Comment: Also the examples at that time were transpiled to support old browsers such as IE.  If you do not need support for old browsers see the more recent examples https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-interactions.html